# Archimedes screw pump

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps

i want to know if an Archimedes screw pump is more eficent that a modern screw pump to elevete clean waters 4 meters i saw many modern screw pumps smaller and  want to now about the efcency of ths two types.

[image]

Comment: Does Archimedes still sell them?

Comment: If Archimedes was the most efficient method and any patent is expired, why would this pump exist?

Comment: totally different beast from an Archimedes (or auger pump. ) Is is this a pressuer pipe application or are both water levels free (open to air)? What is the approximate flowrate? Much variation in this flowrate?

Comment: this is an explanation of an archimed pump: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/what-makes-the-material-travel-through-archimedes-screw/1960#1960

Comment: good help thancs

Comment: the point s that  need to irrgate 150 hectars on a border of a river for alfalfa and corn production.  thaugt  an archmedes screw pump because  need to elevete 3 or 4 meters no more prhaps les than 3 meters m wanted an archmedean one but an small one s dificult to get and transport.  y wanted to do t whith zinc n an menonte or amsh colony that s near they are good in handcraft but construccon is complicate  am thnng what to do

Comment: What's the flow rate and setup of the irrigation system?

Comment: well the land is rented for 2 years for natural cattle breeding  its too difucult that the man who rent an another breeeders use water for doing pasture. the land  is dry rain are near 300 a year bur you can tae water from the rivers  the rver name  is colorado just the border of patagona  the land has a peninsula le a shape then you can tae the water  in dferent points have more than 2500 meters of cost on the river.

Comment: to produce alfalfa for a pasture mix wth clover and a type of rye grass youll need n summer more water for each harvest s about 10 a year wth water s to mae straw bales to sell to others farmer  in dry tmes. f you do alfalfa for seed production a fre lcense one  is less water and cor need a moderate water rate.

Comment: but  d id not mae calculus yet and the sistem  wll be wth a canyon at frst  wll began  in two years. but the rate flow wll be a complex calculus and at frs  have to see de levels of the land exactly .  is plane n general baut for the water a mnmun dfference s a lot. thans for your nterest.  am thnng at frst n water supply. cost and then what really to do.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Moyno, The rubber stator or shell makes it dramatically more efficient than a basic Archimedes type. Moynos develop significant pressure which is not possible in Archimedes.

Answer (score 1):

[I did a reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZis0mpMtC2vWgVdme7y2JjzXDJ9wZXR5zXaMYhFCwPMsfmePoWeSUbjFzzq5Zwo8r1q-0n3Yk0MGZcrGHaSyN5hH_1xQeL-przSiPMw0vCAq1qbiTYpYQDbHSwmEqCe6-zTn3G1f3oK6NBPBfR0tfxzFIMQWzlgmf0CLDIw2m7Qod7G0D7IOMYML6LDNpeApaWgKTbLLm98pLGKfcLK4u5igQ76FfNyDXhS1NJJ4W1_1bCm8ydaCOBb0sNwoPyJ9RVEofSru2deOs5GSMgvXAE-01qTWN-H5da46B3B2ePLvZ6HPR-knemRvRdc8o9UAk3x0yEJGNU&btnG=Search%20by%20image&hl=en), and it seems -- like blacksmith37 said -- that it's a *progressive cavity Mono™ pump* (or [MOYNO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_cavity_pump#:%7E:text=MOYNO)™ for the Americas [no citation]). [This](http://www.imagcompany.com/project/progressive-cavity-mono-single-screw-pumps/) is most likely where the image came from, and [here](http://rotomac.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/e-catalogue-SAC-series.pdf) are the specifics for that pump. Apparently, it specializes in viscous and chunky fluids. It seems pretty nice to me, but then again I'm not a pump expert.

My guess is that because it is an all-purpose, chunky-fluid, non-clogging pipe, it may be less power-efficient (or, more likely, less power-efficient *per cost*, as it may be more expensive) than the **best** models for **clean** water because of its generality. I don't know what screw pumps you're looking at, **but if they're smaller and cheaper than this and will work just as well in clean water, then go for it.** And besides, any energy inefficiency is just a drop in the bucket of our bulky SUVs, Stirling engines, and burning oil wells.

Oh, and if I made a mistake, or you have more information, please comment! Thank you!

Comment: @mart Ooookay... I'll pretend to understand that.

Comment: very clear thancs . t s a good help´for me

Comment: @mart Whoopsies! Corrected now. Thank you.